# When I am doing bower install I am getting error

Tags: installation, bower

When I am doing bower install i am getting error like

bower bootstrap-tagsinput#~0.7.1 ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy ~0.7.1

Additional error details:
No versions found in https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput.git

Can anyone suggest a solution for this error

I was expecting bower install with no errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.